# Laravel 4: Running composer when deploying to Heroku

Tags: php, deployment, heroku, laravel, composer-php

I've been searching everywhere for an answer to this.

I built an app in Laravel - I chose Heroku for deployment, I included a custom Procfile and httpd.conf to rewrite the document root to public. That all works great.

However my app shows an internal 500 error upon loading because it hasn't loaded any dependencies i.e. not run composer upon deployment.

**My question is: how do I make composer run upon deployment?**

p.s. I'm a total noob with this kind of stuff so please provide as much detail as possible.

The only possible solution I've seen is here: http://bergie.iki.fi/blog/using_composer_to_manage_dependencies_in_heroku_php_apps/

But I'm convinced there is better way than this.

Comment: if you find the answer useful please upvote it and if the answer is correct accept it and upvote it, Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

#### Composer Fix

You need to generate and include `composer.lock` in the repo, but Laravel's default `.gitignore` ignores `composer.lock`

- Remove `composer.lock` from `.gitignore`
- `$ composer install`

#### Add your Procfile

Heroku knows which processes to run for your app based on a configuration file called a `Procfile`. The default `apache2` process (if you don't use a `Procfile`) points to the `web root`, not to `/public`, so we need to create a custom `Procfile` to serve the site from `/public`.

- Add a file with the name Procfile that contains this line:

  `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public`

#### Deploy your code to the Heroku app

```
$ git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible cause is that Heroku doesn't recognize your app as a PHP app, for example because of the presence of package.json in the root. And so it doesn't do composer install for you.

Solution is to specify a buildpack, and do a push again.

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php
```

See also:
[Heroku doesn't recognize my Laravel app as PHP app, and does not do composer install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27741478/heroku-doesnt-recognize-my-laravel-app-as-php-app-and-does-not-do-composer-ins/27741701#27741701)