# Heroku doesn't recognize my Laravel app as PHP app, and does not do composer install

Tags: php, heroku, laravel-4, composer-php

I'm trying to publish my Laravel app on Heroku.
I have excluded the composer.lock file from .gitignore, and created a Procfile containing

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public
```

I created my app with

```
heroku create myapp;
git push heroku master;
```

Then I get the following output:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v --tags heroku master:master 
Pushing to https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git
POST git-receive-pack (1914 bytes)
remote: Compressing source files... done.        
remote: Building source:        
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected        
remote: -----> Resetting git environment        
remote: 
remote:        PRO TIP: Specify a node version in package.json        
remote:        See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support        
remote: 
remote: -----> Defaulting to latest stable node: 0.10.35        
remote: -----> Downloading and installing node        
remote: -----> Exporting config vars to environment        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies        
remote:        npm WARN package.json myapp@0.0.0 No repository field.        
remote: -----> Cleaning up node-gyp and npm artifacts        
remote: -----> Building runtime environment        
remote: -----> Discovering process types        
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web        
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 9.6MB        
remote: -----> Launching... done, v5        
remote:        https://myapp.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku        
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.        
To https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git
   5b1c663..0dff021  master -> master
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/heroku/master'
Completed successfully
```

If I browse to my app, however I get an application error.
When I look to my logs, it says

```
app[web.1]: bash: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2: No such file or directory
```

I suspect that somehow, **Heroku didn't do composer install**, as it's not in my git output, and maybe it didn't even recognize that my app is an PHP app?
To be sure, I also included an empty index.php file in my root. Didn't help.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 12):

I believe I found it. Should better read the lines ("Node.js app detected").
Solved by firing this command :

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php
```

and pushing again

Comment: This didn't work for me.  But `heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php` as per [this link](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php) worked.

Comment: Thanks Raghuram, the above didn't work me either, but the command you provided did :-)

Answer (score 1):

Haha, just simply drop the `package.json` in your laravel project.
And then Heroku will detect your app as a php project.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include the trailing slash on `public`: `public/`. This was my issue - I am using Laravel and got a `Image source not readable` and `NotReadableException in AbstractDecoder.php line 302:` because it thought `at AbstractDecoder->init('/app/public') in AbstractDriver.php line 64` was a file, not a folder.